# ASP.NET MVC many to many relationship error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

This is my controller :

```
  public ActionResult PPKPIChart()
    {
        return View();
    }
        public ActionResult PPKPI()
    {
        var dt = db.Sales
               .Where(ol => ol.SaleId != null)
               .GroupBy(ol => ol.PPUsers.Where(p => p.Name != null))
               .ToList()
               .Select(g => new object[] {
                       g.Key,
                       g.Count()
                   }); ;
        return Json(dt, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here is my view :

```
@section foot {
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script>
    google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(init);

    let dt, opt, cht;

    function init() {
        dt = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        // TODO: Data table columns
        dt.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        dt.addColumn('number', 'KPI');

        let style = { bold: true, italic: false, fontSize: 20, color: 'purple' };

        opt = {
            title: 'Prepress Personnel KPI',
            fontName: 'calibri',
            fontSize: 14,
            titleTextStyle: { fontSize: 20 },
            chartArea: {
                width: '80%',
                height: '70%',
                top: 60,
                left: 80
            },
            // TODO: vAxis, hAxis, legend, animation, orientation
            vAxis: {
                title: 'KPI',
                titleTextStyle: style
            },
            hAxis: {
                title: 'Name',
                titleTextStyle: style
            },
            legend: 'none',
            animation: {
                duration: 500,
                startup: true
            },
            orientation: 'horizontal',
        };

        cht = new google.visualization.ColumnChart($('#chart')[0]);

        $('#reload').click();
    }

    $('#reload').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let url = '/Home/PPKPI';
        let param = {};

        $.getJSON(url, param, function (json) {
            dt.removeRows(0, dt.getNumberOfRows());
            dt.addRows(json);
            cht.draw(dt, opt);
        });
    });

    $('#toggle').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // TODO: Toggle orientation (horizontal <--> vertical)
        opt.orientation = opt.orientation == 'horizontal' ?
                          'vertical' : 'horizontal';
        [opt.vAxis, opt.hAxis] = [opt.hAxis, opt.vAxis];

        cht.draw(dt, opt);
    });
</script>
```

This is my entity framework which have many to many relationships

[image]

I want to show a bar chart but because of many to many relationships I cannot do so especially at

```
GroupBy(ol => ol.PPUsers.Where(p => p.Name != null)) -- > i guess this is the issues behind it.. my query in this line is not working
```

Basically the relationships look like this :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 `public ActionResult TotalJobAssignedData()<br/>
    {
        var dt = db.PPUsers
               .ToList()
               .Select(g => new object[] {
                       g.Name, 
                       g.Sales.Count()
               });
        return Json(dt, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems related `PPUsers` entities could not be loaded into `Sales` entity.

You can follow [Eagerly Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data#eagerly-loading) approach:

> Eager loading is the process whereby a query for one type of entity
> also loads related entities as part of the query. Eager loading is
> achieved by use of the Include method.

To do so you can use `Include` to load related entities as follows:

```
 var dt = db.Sales
           .Include(s => s.PPUsers)
           .Where(ol => ol.SaleId != null)
           .GroupBy(ol => ol.PPUsers.Where(p => p.Name != null))
           .ToList()
           .Select(g => new object[] {
                   g.Key,
                   g.Count()
               });
```

Entity Framework supports three ways to load related data - eager loading, lazy loading and explicit loading. Have a look at [Loading Related Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data).

Comment: thank you for the link. Greatly help me. I have solved it using different approach

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark answer as an accepted (click on the check mark beside the answer)  so that it helps to others.